# How to prevent broken audio src from printing error message in console?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where the user clicks a button and a audio starts to play.

```
<button onclick="playAudio()">Play</button>
```

But if the source url is incorrect, it prints in the console:

> **Uncaught (in promise) NotSupportedError: failed to load because no supported source was found**

```
var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.src = "myAudioSrc (incorrect url)";

function playAudio(){
    myAudio.play();
    //prints error
}
```

How to prevent this error message in console if the source url is incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is generated when you call `.play()`, not when you assign the invalid `src`. To suppress it, as the error indicates, you need to `catch` the error thrown by the promise that `.play()` returns:

```js
var myAudio = new Audio();
myAudio.src = "myAudioSrc (incorrect url)";
console.log('src has been assigned');
myAudio.play()
  .catch(() => void 0);
```

Because embedded snippets wouldn't show the error anyway, here's an example on JSFiddle to illustrate the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/smjy5b9u/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `catch` the promise returned (if any), even though this message is IMM Chrome's implementation just being too verbose.

```js
var p = new Audio('foo').play();
// check we actually have a Promise (older browser may not return this)
if(p)
  p.catch(function(e){/*silent*/});
```