# Request was interrupted by a call to pause() on Chrome66

Tags: javascript

I am receiving this error from Chrome66.

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()
```

Here is my script. I have no idea what is the issue.

```
<script>
    jwplayer().on('viewable', function (e) {
        (e.viewable) ? jwplayer().play(): jwplayer().pause();
    });
    jwplayer().on('displayClick',function(){
        jwplayer().play(); jwplayer().pause();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does your script do what you expected it to do? If so, just ignore this message. Chrome is very verbose for `MediaElement.play()`'s promise, which is one serious point against this feature. If you really want to make it not print in console, then you'd probably have to tweak your lib so they [`catch` the returned Promise if any](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50404189/3702797).

Comment: ok i guess i am ignoring this.